# why my Loki log retention is not working?

Tags: purge, retention, grafana-loki, promtail

"12h" old logs are not deleting even after specifying "retention_period: 12h" due to this I'm facing storage issue because, log are not deleting.
please help me with config

```
loki:
  enabled: true
  isDefault: true
  table_manager:
    retention_deletes_enabled: true
    retention_period: 12h
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "12h" old logs are not deleting? I am asking because Loki is not supposed to delete any log file. To delete those files, you would use some kind of log rotation provided by your logging framework. (BTW: Getting those files is part of the Promtail configuration not part of Loki.)

Comment: Actually, My goal is to deleted logs which are older than 12h, it should be deleted from  grafana dashboard as well as from server storage because I m facing storage issues as my log are not deleting, and occupying huge space in server storage is getting full

Answer (score 7):

I have the following configurations related to log retention:

```
...
compactor:
  ...
  retention_enabled: true
...
limits_config:
  ...
  retention_period: 90d
...
```

See more about Loki configuration in the documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/)

Answer (score 5):

[Grafana Loki Storage Retention](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/retention/)

> By default, when `table_manager.retention_deletes_enabled` or
> `compactor.retention_enabled` *flags are not set*, **then logs sent to
> Loki live forever.**

**The minimum retention period is 24h**.

The retention period **must be a multiple** of the *index* and chunks table `period`, configured in the `period_config` block.

Sample config:

```yaml
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 24h
```

The other way to setup the retention in Grafana Loki is via the Compactor.

```yaml
limits_config:
  retention_period: 168h

compactor:
  working_directory: /data/retention
  compaction_interval: 10m
  retention_enabled: true
  retention_delete_delay: 2h
  retention_delete_worker_count: 150

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h
```

Note that **retention is only available if the index period is 24h**.

To purge data immediately you could set the `retention_delete_delay` interval to `1m`. This is a delay after which chunks will be fully deleted during retention.

Do not forget to restart Loki after changing the configuration:

```bash
systemctl restart loki
systemctl status loki
```

Comment: `This is a delay after which chunks will be fully deleted during retention` I do not understand. So the logs will be deleted after retention_delete_delay or after limits_config: retention_period? Why are there two settings?

Comment: `retention_delete_delay` just delays deleting defined in `limits_config\retention_period`. The reason for that is described in https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/retention/ as:
"1. ... deleting chunks instantly could lead to components still having reference to old chunks and so they could fails to execute queries. Having a delay allows for components to refresh their store and so remove gracefully their reference of those chunks.
2. It provides a short window of time in which to cancel chunk deletion in the case of a configuration mistake."

Comment: Hi, do you have an idea, if they support using 1w for retention, for example. It is a bit confusing that you can use the unit of time "h", but you must use multiples of 24h. Why they just did not enforce using the unit "d"? Or can we use d or w or m? I could not find this info the docs.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Grafana storage documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/storage/#retention):

> With the exception of the filesystem chunk store, Loki will not delete old chunk stores. This is generally handled instead by configuring TTLs (time to live) in the chunk store of your choice (bucket lifecycles in S3/GCS, and TTLs in Cassandra). Neither will Loki currently delete old data when your local disk fills when using the filesystem chunk store – deletion is only determined by retention duration.

This quote should answer your question. You need to configure bucket lifecycles in your storage provider to be able to delete chunk stores.